# How can I plot $A(a,b) = 2\cos(2b-a+1)$

Tags: graphing-functions

$A_{1}(a,b) = 2\cos(2b-a+1)$

$A_{2}(a,b) = 2\cos(-2b-a+1)$

$A_{3}(a,b) = 2\cos(2b+a+1)$

I want to know which waves are moving $+a$ or $-a$

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by "How can I plot.."? Are you looking for specific plotting software? (There are plenty)  Or suggestions on how to plot two variable functions in general?

Comment: Is b the variable of time? If not, what do you mean by 'moving'?